# Tensorflow with GPU support on Mac High Sierra 10.13.4 with AMD Radeon Pro 450 2048 MB?

Tags: tensorflow, opencl

Want to instal run tensorflow programs using GPU support in macbook pro. These are my system specs with AMD Radeon Pro 450. 
[image]

I have read that some people are using the OpenCl or some are using the cuda.

Can't find any good solution. Please help.

Comment: CUDA will only work with nvidia cards, and only if you install the "web" drivers from nvidia's website. So that won't work on yours. macOS supports OpenCL and Metal 2 Compute on High Sierra for general purpose GPU computation with that hardware; I can't comment on Tensorflow, as I've never used it.

Comment: I have tried to use my gpu for tensorflow training but I think that right now this Radeon Pro 450 GPU is not supported by the tensorflow libraries. May be in coming days It will be supported. Tensorflow gives warning that i can use gpu for better computations.

If anyone have a solution to use this Radeon Pro 450 gpu with tensorflow please comment or past the links.

Comment: Looks like there might some possible workarounds here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22 - I have no experience with them (or TensorFlow) myself.